# slam using rplidar A1 in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, lidar

Does anyone know a proper package for slam using rplidar in python “without ROS” and in Raspberry Pi 4, I have been trying to find some code or a package which could help me build a robot using these parts, but mostly they are not working

Comment: Here's a few that I found https://github.com/SkoltechRobotics/rplidar https://github.com/ryan-brazeal-ufl/RPyLIDAR  https://github.com/Hyun-je/pyrplidar. It will work with RPi4 because it supports python. "but mostly they are not working" you don't specify which packages are not working so I might have found same ones

Comment: @Combinacijus currently, i am working with https://github.com/simondlevy/BreezySLAM this

Comment: Oh I didn't notice slam part my bad. I found that [this project](https://github.com/AerospaceRobotics/RPLidar-SLAMbot) also uses BreezySLAM so maybe it is a good choice. Other than that it will be hard to find rplidar and slam in one place because it's very specific better bet would be to find rplidar and slam in separate packages and combine them. Sorry I can't help much on this I'm more familiar with ROS and [C++ packages](https://github.com/iris-ua/iris_lama) because efficiency